# Dragging of the form moves the form down

Tags: c#, windows

I have a Windows Form, My task is to add drag function to the form. "VendorMasterList" is a label. I have added mouse move, mouse down and mouse up events to that label.

[image]

If i tried to drag, the form moves down and then only able to drag the way i want. My question is why its going down?This is my code

```
   private Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
   private bool isDragging = false;

   private void lblHeader_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       isDragging = true;  // _dragging is your variable flag
       startPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    private void lblHeader_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       isDragging = false;
    }
     private void lblHeader_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
            {
                Point p = PointToScreen(e.Location);
                this.Location = new Point(p.X - this.startPoint.X, p.Y - this.startPoint.Y);
            }
     }
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Newly added image

[image]

Comment: are you trying to move the header or the form.. as "this.location" moves the form...

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to use custom chrome like this? What's wrong with keeping the window as is and letting the *user* choose how it's going to look? If you insist, have a look at how the non-client area works in Windows - it's quite easy to either redraw the non-client area any way you want, extend it or even just pretend that a part of the client area of the window is actually a non-client area that corresponds to the header (and let Windows do the dragging for you).

Comment: If the mouse moves over the label and clicks . the position of the form is changed.

Comment: you could try accounting for the difference between the ClientSize of the Form and the actual size of the form - `this.Location = new Point(p.X - this.startPoint.X, p.Y - this.startPoint.Y - (this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height));`

Comment: @Luaan do u have any example to explain

Comment: @KeithHall Still going down and then only able to drag the way i want

Comment: You really only need to handle the [WM_NCHITTEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) message, and return `HTCAPTION`, when the mouse position is inside your 'caption'. Forward the default value for anything else. And that's it. With that your form will magically move, like any other form that hasn't been bastardized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven' tried your code, but what I see is only partially correct :-)

You save the initial coordinate, which is relative to the **upper left corner** of the control that's clicked, but you need to save **screen coordinates**.

Then the mouse is moved and again you get a point relative to that corner. You're missing a few relevant things:

1. You need to calculate a delta between the two points based on the **screen** coordinates, otherwise moving the window underneath the cursor gives you wrong values.
2. You need to add this delta to the form's **current location**
3. You need to save the new mouse position to calculate the next delta correctly

The current mouse position based on screen coordinates can be obtained through `Cursor.Position`.

So your code should read:

```
private void lblHeader_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   isDragging = true;  // _dragging is your variable flag
   startPoint = Cursor.Position;
}

private void lblHeader_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   isDragging = false;
}

private void lblHeader_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        Point p = Cursor.Position;
        int deltaX = p.X - startPoint.X;
        int deltaY = p.Y - startPoint.Y;
        startPoint = p;

        this.Left += deltaX;
        this.Top += deltaY;
    }
 }
```

I just placed a panel on a form and implented the above, which worked.

---

@IInspector is right when he says that this approach is actually not very good, as it doesn't take into account that Windows can actually handle all this for you.

An alternative approach (and the better one) I'd take is:

1. Override the `WndProc` method as shown below
2. Done. No more mouse handling

The following is an example of how you could override WndProc to do what you need:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const UInt32 WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    const UInt32 HTCAPTION = 0x2;

    bool handled = false;
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        if (<cursor is within the caption area>)
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
            handled = true;
        }
    }

    if (!handled)
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

---

To restrict the area in which the window can be moved, you could use the following. Of course, @IInspectable will disagree, but you went this road :-)

```
private void lblHeader_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        Point p = Cursor.Position;
        int deltaX = p.X - startPoint.X;
        int deltaY = p.Y - startPoint.Y;
        startPoint = p;

        int fX = this.Left + deltaX;
        int fY = this.Top + deltaY;

        if (fX >= 0 && fX + this.Width < Area.Width) this.Left = fX;
        if (fY >= 0 && f> + this.Height < Area.Height) this.Top = fY;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please, don't. It started so wrong that I had to downvote even before seeing an updated version. Windows already does everything for you, there really is nothing your program has to do, other than appropriately handling the [WM_NCHITTEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) message. Simply return `HTCAPTION` for the respective area, and be done with it. Everything else simply works (and that includes moving the form around).

Comment: @IInspectable Well, that's not my fault. The OP has this code already, the OP wanted to know why his code does not work, I gave a correct answer. You may not be satisfied with this, but that's really not my problem or a problem with my answer. Of course I know about WM_NCHITTEST, but that's not the way the OP is going. Otherwise my answer is fully correct in that it works and does exactly what the OP wants. All you say is correct, but I don't see a reason for a downvote. Feel free to write your own answer outlining your approach.

Comment: @IInspectable I included your approach as an alternative into my answer.

Comment: That's a very [Eulenspiegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Till_Eulenspiegel)-like response. Instead of giving a robust solution, you merely helped the OP shooting their own foot more effectively. And it's not even good advice. It fails for rapid mouse movements, or when pressing the [Esc] key. This type of *"answer is not useful"*, hence the downvote.

Comment: Let me browse about  WM_NCHITTEST also

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i used the first code only because i don't know what the second code is doing. But i will learn to use that also. i have a question. Please find the newly attached image. The form goes out of the dashboard. Is there any way we can restrict this.

Comment: You could calculate the new `x` and `y` coordinate for the form and then check whether both of them are >= 0 and `x + Width < DashBoard.Width` and `y + Height < DashBoard.Height`. Only change the location of the form when these conditions are given.

Comment: Once more, a convoluted solution, that appears to work, but fails on closer inspection. Again, the system already offers everything you need. In this case it is [ClipCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383.aspx).

Comment: And once more I encourage you to post your own anwer, but obviously it is much easier to critizise existing answers than providing your master solution. And `ClipCursor` is even more complicated in this case, as you'd have to calculate the rectangle in which the *cursor* can move. I let the cursor move freely, but stop moving the window.

Comment: @IInspectable actually i don't know how to use WndProc in my scenario. Can you tell me

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar For the last formula that u suggested. x is the form location x , width is form width so i wrote something like this if (startPoint.X > 0 && startPoint.Y > 0
                        && (this.Width) < 1008
                        && (this.Height) < 691)
                    {
                        this.Left += deltaX;
                        this.Top += deltaY;
                    } 1008 is my dashboard width 691 is dashboard height

Comment: Calculating the rectangle in which the mouse can move to confine a rectangular area to another, larger rectangular area is trivially easy. Even if it weren't, using `ClipCursor` is superior to justify additional work. For one, it doesn't suffer from the glitch where the mouse cursor moves relative to the window, that cannot move down any further. And it doesn't produce the jitter, caused by the system moving the window, and then you adjusting its position. I'm not providing an answer, because C# is outside my field of expertise.

Comment: @IInspectable ok ill try and reply you

Comment: @user2115618 Yes, it doesn't work because you did it wrong. Try this `int formX = this.Left + deltaX; int formY = this.Top + deltaY; if (formX >= 0 && formX + this.Width < DashBoard.Width) this.Left = formX; if (formY >= 0 && formY + this.Height < DashBoard.Height) this.Top = formY;`. Instead of `this.Left += deltaX; this.Top += deltaY;`.

Comment: @user2115618 I modified the answer to include this code as well. Please replace `Area.Width` and `Area.Height` with your dimensions.

Comment: Of course I will disagree, when you offer a solution that isn't. All the more **after** I already explained, why this is inferior, and even spelled out the correct solution. Sorry, there's your -1 again.

Comment: I can well live with that.

Comment: Why then did you remove the very first incarnation of your proposed answer, because it exhibited too much jitter? Your kludge to force mouse movement to a rectangular area not only causes jitter, but also flickers a scrollbar, whenever you hit the wrong edge.

Comment: Because the window actually jumped. It doesn't now, and it worked well for me even rapidly moving the mouse. The scrollbar issue isn't an issue if you mind the correct dimensions. And this, to me, is the end of this discussion, as I actually don't give a bit whether you like my answer or not. Was it me I'd have reconsidered my design as I'm not a friend of multiple window applications, but it is for the OP and that's totally fine with me.